# refactoring/making the code better in javascript

Tags: javascript, refactoring, facebook-like

im currently a complete noob at programming ,but i'm taking courses and about to start a bootcamp, at the moment im doing challenges in Codewars, one of the challenges was to create a function that would simulate the facebook like system.

```
function likes(names) {
    if(names.length === 2){
    return `${names[0]} and ${names[1]} like this`;
    } else if (names.length === 3){
      return `${names[0]}, ${names[1]} and ${names[2]} like this`;
    } else if (names.length >= 4){
      return `${names[0]}, ${names[1]} and ${names.length-2} others like this`;
    } else if (names.length === 0){
      return `no one likes this`;
    } 
    else{
      return `${names} likes this`
    }
}
```

I tried the code and it works and passed everything but i was wondering if there was any other way more "pro" or better to refactor this code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may consider using a switch statement instead of multiple else ifs

Comment: Switch-case statements are the same as `if`s as far as I'm concerned but uglier. It doesn't fix the underlying problem that you have to write `n` branches. I think it's a common misconception that `switch` is somehow a solution to long `if` chains. If there were more options, a table lookup or pattern-based approach is the normal refactoring approach but it'd be overkill for this. On Codewars, you can look at other people's solutions and decide which is best. Anyway, I'm voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Working code which is asked for improvement should is better posted at [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use switch statement here. Chaining so many else if's is considered bad practice.

You can read about switch statement here. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Code would look something like:

```
function likes(names) {
    if(names.length<0) {
         return `${names} likes this`; //return early if possible
    }
    let answer = '';
        switch (names.length) {
          case 0:
            answer = `no one likes this`;
            break;
          case 2:          
            answer = `${names[0]} and ${names[1]} like this`;
            break;
          case 3:
            answer = `${names[0]}, ${names[1]} and ${names[2]} like this`;
            break;
          case 4:
          default:
            answer = `${names[0]}, ${names[1]} and ${names.length-2} others like this`;      
        }
    
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: cool thank you very much!

Comment: you are welcome, keep on learning.

Answer (score 0):

Using array destructuring, you can simplify this.

```js
function likes(names = []) {
  if (names.length === 0) {
    return `no one likes this`;
  }
  let [first, second, third, ...rest] = names;
  if (rest.length) {
    third = `${rest.length + 1} others`;
  }
  if (third) {
    return `${first}, ${second} and ${third} like this`;
  }
  if (second) {
    return `${first} and ${second} like this`;
  }
  return `${first} likes this`;
}
console.log(likes(["name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4", "name 5"]));
console.log(likes(["name 1", "name 2", "name 3"]));
console.log(likes(["name 1", "name 2"]));
console.log(likes(["name 1"]));
console.log(likes());

// name 1, name 2 and 3 others like this
// name 1, name 2 and name 3 like this
// name 1 and name 2 like this
// name 1 likes this
// no one likes this
```

Comment: wow thanks! i haven't reached that part yet lol, but anyways is good to know that exists! thanks